# Displaying edit count on MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-extensions

I would like to display number of edits / contribution on user page. Is there any way to do that?

I tried to use link mentioned here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:User_contributions

So if follow that, I got a URL something like this:

```
http://ourdomain/api.php?action=query&list=users&ususers=MYUSERNAME&usprop=editcount
```

And if I use it, it shows me a page with correct edit count. But it shows as XML like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<api>
  <query>
   <users>
      <user name="USERNAME" editcount="728" />
   </users>
  </query>
</api>
```

On this XML page, I can see the correct edit count. But I just want to display it as a count on a different page. Something like "**Total number of edits: 728**". We are using MediaWiki 1.15.5-7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have already found what you are looking for! The API will give you the best estimate of a user's editcount. You can add Javascript to be run on each pageview to `MediaWiki:Common.js`, to inject this data into the user page. In your API call, append `&format=json` to get a more JS friendly format.

If, for some reason, you do not want to use Javascript here, you could [write your own extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Developing_extensions) to handle this in the backend. This can be implemented as a [parser function](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parser_functions), to be invoked like `{{USERCONTRIBS:UserName}}`, or similar. The method you are looking for is [`User::getEditCount()`](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/html/classUser.html#a964fd2c9e0bba7f28208447af752dfc1). To get the user object, you can use `User::newFromName`. This, however, would require the user pages to be purged on each pageload, making them a lot slower to load, or you would have to accept that the count in not always up to date.

There might also be some existing extensions that let you print the edit count. I know for sure that [`Extension:SemanticExtraSpecialProperties`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Semantic_Extra_Special_Properties) does, though that depends on the whole SemanticMediawiki package. For an example of how to display user statistics with SMW+SESP, see [this page](http://xn--ssongsmat-v2a.nu/ssm/S%C3%A4songsmat:Anv%C3%A4ndarlista).

Comment: I wanted to pass that result to another Wiki page. As I mentioned earlier, I wanted to display "Total number of edits: 728" on another wiki page. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: You could create a [parser function](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parser_functions), but as pages are not rendered on pageview, it would not be in sync. If you need the exact count, use JS. Also, if you are using Semantic MediaWiki, there is [an extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Semantic_Extra_Special_Properties) that can give you what I want (I use it myself to display user contributions [here](http://xn--ssongsmat-v2a.nu/ssm/S%C3%A4songsmat:Anv%C3%A4ndarlista))